# EOF character in file upload causing mod security to return 403

Tags: html, apache, mod-security

I have the following form that posts 2 fields and a file.

```
<form id="uploadNewForm" action="/upload-new" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" novalidate="novalidate">
    <select id="customerNumber" name="customerNumber"><option value="0001">0001</option></select>
    <input id="file" name="file" type="file" value="">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" name="fileUpload">
    <textarea id="comments" name="comments" maxlength="1000" style="height: 100%;"></textarea> 
</form>
```

A user recently tried to upload a .pdf file that contained a EOF character within it. This seems to have caused mod-security to reject the request due to

> Match of "eq 0" against "MULTIPART_UNMATCHED_BOUNDARY" required

I am assuming that mod security is considering the request done once it hits the EOF character.

I do not wish to tell all users that if they get a 403 error to recreate the file in hopes that it doesn't contain the EOF character.

What are my options? Could the browser encode the file somehow by some setting in the html form so modsecurity doesn't see the EOF character? or can mod security be configured to ignore EOF characters until the POST request is truly completed?

Comment: Do you know (or can you find) the rule ID of this rule?

Comment: I am a developer and only have access to certain logs. In our log displaying app I see the following.  

Message:Accessdeniedwithcode403 (phase2).Matchof "eq0" against "MULTIPART_UNMATCHED_BOUNDARY" required. [file "/etc/httpd/conf.d/mod_security.conf"] [line "96"] [msg "Multipartparserdetectedapossibleunmatchedboundary."] Action:Intercepted (phase2) Apache-Handler:weblogic-handler

Answer (score 3):

Although I do not have anything to add to @ahjohnston25's fix/workaround for this issue, I can hopefully shed some light on the root cause of the issue.

In the past, there were MIME parsers that had bugs that could be tripped by sticking CR-LF-dash-dash in the data stream, because they would treat any line starting with "--" as a MIME part separator. The MULTIPART_UNMATCHED_BOUNDARY detects this situation.

I haven't seen such badly written MIME parsers in years, so I feel safe to remove rule 960915 (and its cousin, 200003), on systems I maintain.

As it turns out, PDF will marshall some data streams into strings that contains newline-dash-dash, so there's a bigger change of hitting this false positive with PDF uploads than there is with, say, JPEG (but I've seen this one trigger with JPEG too, pot luck). Given that there's no alternative to MIME uploads in today's web (short of requiring your users to ZIP up all PDF's), getting the rule whitelisted is the only way to make PDF uploads reliable.

When you have a PDF file that reproduces the issue, do yourself a favor and save it. Get modsecurity on your development box and reproduce the issue. Then, with this rule disabled, try to upload it to your app and checksum it. If you don't see any corruption, you have proven that this particular codepath does not trip over lines that look like a MIME header, and you could try to convince your sysadmin to put in an exception for your particular URI.

If he refuses, work your way up the management chain, explaining that you've done your homework and he hasn't. If he refuses and you have a customer/vendor relationship, consider switching vendors.

Reproducing such issues has saved my bacon, for example that time when users complained about not being able to upload files with a quote in the filename. I could reproduce the issue, but after removing the rule on my development system, I saw an SQL error when trying to upload the offending file. Oops. Not sure if Joomla fixed the bug in the mean time, but for now, that particular rule stays.

YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

While not the best option, you can disable the rule (which has rule ID of #960915) by running the following command:

```
echo "SecRuleRemoveById 960915" >> /etc/httpd/conf.d/modsecurity.conf
```

Or wherever your modsecurity.conf file is located.

EDIT: Updated the line to use the location of modsecurity.conf for you particular install. I will leave the above line in as its location is not standardized.

Comment: The administrator are not willing to remove or set the rule to logging only.

Comment: You can disable the rule for a specific path using the `<Location>` tag (so it wouldn't check for that rule on that form only). Other than that, I don't think there is any alternative (as you cannot control what your form's input will be).